# How to stop/exit a HostBuilder console application - IApplicationLifetime?

Tags: c#, .net-core, console-application

I'm creating a .net core console application and am using `HostBuilder` which I haven't used before. This is for a webjob that populates a database with components. Once it's finished executing the task that populates the database, then the application should stop.So far the app runs as follows:

```
class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var serviceHost = new HostBuilder();

            serviceHost.ConfigureServices(sc =>
            {
               // configure all services here 
            });

           await serviceHost.RunConsoleAsync();
        }
    }
```

What I can't work out how to do is to exit the console app without having to press Ctrl + C. I have seen a few Stack Overflow articles asking similar questions with a variety of suggestions, the most popular being `IApplicationLifetime`; however I'm unsure how to implement this here, if it even is the right way to go?

Comment: Are you running .net Core?

Comment: yes @Demodave, I'll update my question to say so

Comment: If you don't want to use Crtl + C then what will be the signal to send to the application so it knows it should stop?

Comment: @CodeNotFound this is for a webjob that populates a database with components. Once it's finished executing the task that populates the database, then the application should stop. I'll update my question with this too

Comment: `HostBuilder` is arguably the wrong model. If you want to be in control of the application's lifetime, just write a plain old console application. When `Main` exits, so does the application as a whole. There is no need to get fancy. You can still have DI for your services by rigging up a standalone `ServiceProvider`, if desired (though that too is optional).